# the type of schema applied to the document is not supported package.json

Tags: json, visual-studio, package.json

Can anyone explain what this warning in my package.json file is?  I have searched a little bit but I cannot seem to understand if this is just compatibility/strange behavior or if there is something going on worse than that.

I have taken a screenshot of the warning message below.
I apologize if this has been answered elsewhere and I overlooked it.

[image]

Attached is my package.json in full:

```
{
    "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
    "version": 1,
    "projects": {
        "project": {
            "architect": {
                "lint": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:tslint",
                    "options": {
                        "exclude": [ "**/node_modules/**" ],
                        "tsConfig": [ "tsconfig.json" ]
                    }
                },
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        "aot": true,
                        "assets": [ "src/favicon.ico" ],
                        "index": "src/index.html",
                        "main": "src/main.ts",
                        "outputPath": "dist",
                        "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
                        "scripts": [
                            "node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit.min.js",
                            "node_modules/uikit/dist/js/uikit-icons.min.js"
                        ],
                "styles": [
                "node_modules/uikit/dist/css/uikit.min.css",
                "src/styles.scss",
                "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
                ],
                        "tsConfig": "tsconfig.json"
                    },
                    "configurations": {
                        "development": {
                            "baseHref": "/aspnetcoreangular/",
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "vendorChunk": false
                        },
                        "production": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.production.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "baseHref": "/aspnetcoreangular/",
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "vendorChunk": false
                        },
                        "staging": {
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.staging.ts"
                                }
                            ],
                            "baseHref": "/aspnetcoreangular/",
                            "buildOptimizer": true,
                            "extractCss": true,
                            "extractLicenses": true,
                            "namedChunks": false,
                            "optimization": true,
                            "outputHashing": "all",
                            "sourceMap": false,
                            "vendorChunk": false
                        }
                    }
                },
                "serve": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
                    "options": { "browserTarget": "project:build" }
                }
            },
            "cli": {
                "warnings": {
                    "typescriptMismatch": false,
                    "versionMismatch": false
                }
            },
            "prefix": "app",
            "projectType": "application",
            "root": "",
            "sourceRoot": "src"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: For what it's worth, this appears to be related.  No real answer, though.  https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/276376/intellisense-does-not-work-for-json-schema.html

Answer (score 22, accepted):

https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-json-schema-draft-06-draft-07/796216

VS still doesn't support draft 7 for json-schemes and is stuck at draft 4-5. Hence the warning.

It's a false positive.

**EDIT**

Mike (see below) suggests a work around. Be sure to check it out and give Mike an upvote if it works (so that he'll be the first answer listed).

Comment: There is a simple fix. see my answer below.

Answer (score 22):

In Visual Studio, Change the Schema dropdown at the top of the file to :
https://json.schemastore.org/global.json

Ref: https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/support-json-schema-draft-06-draft-07/796216

Comment: Thx. I hope the edit works for you. Take care & good luck.